# How to upload html input file in chunks?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, file-upload

I can upload the whole file at once like this:

```js
myInput.onchange = ({ target }) => {
  const file = target.files[0];

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("fileData", file);

  // ...then I post "formData" to server
}
```

I want to know how to properly upload it in small chunks?

Comment: Do I need to implement server side logic too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using Dropzone library